# Quantity in Inches to Convert to Feet, Centimeters or Yards Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects, innerhtml

The instructions goes as follows:

1. Ask the user to enter a quantity in inches (in a textbox).
2. Have a select box with options for: Feet, Centimeters, Yards.
3. If they chose inches, calculate the conversion as 1 inch = 0.0833 feet. For Centimeters: 1 inch = 2.54 centimeters. For Yards, 1 inch = 0.02778.
4. Because the user may enter a decimal amoung (e.g. 3.99), be sure to parse using the `parseFloat` option.
5. Using a reference: Look up the `toFixed()` function and make sure that your result is outputted to 2 decimal places.
6. Output to a div section called `results`. Output using the `innerHTML` command.

This is the code that I currently have in place

```js
function convertCurrency(r) {
  document.getElementById("cnvrtMoney").innerHTML = "output";

  if (dropdown == "feetConversion".parseFloat(r)) {
    Convert = Convert / 0.0833;
  } else if (dropdown == "centimetersConversion".parseFloat(r)) {
    Convert = Convert / 2.54;
  } else if (dropdown == "yardsConversion".parseFloat(r)) {
    Convert = Convert / 0.02778;
  }

  Convert = Convert.toFixed(2);

  var resultsString = "The amount would be" + Convert;
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsString;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#heading {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}

#formConverter {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: auto;
}

#EndResults {
  background-color: darkgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment 01: Currency Converter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading">
    <h1> Currency Converter </h1>
    <img src="CurrencyConverter.jpg" alt="Currency Converter Banner" width="600" height="200">
  </div>
  <div id="formConverter">
    <form action="CurrencyConverter.php" method="get">
      Enter Quantity (In Inches): <input type="text" name="inputInches" /><br> Select Conversion:
      <select name="dropdown">
        <option value="feetConversion">Feet </option>
        <option value="centimetersConversion">Centimeters </option>
        <option value="yardsConversion">Yards </option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to make it display once the user clicks on the dropdown button with the exact conversion that it needs to be. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You do know that you're missing parentheses on the second `else if`, right?

Comment: yes, I have just fixed it now

Comment: Ok, I'm on it...

Comment: @AnnaMarkiewicz You didn't fix it, I just did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is JavaScript code, you do not need `<form>`.
Second, to access elements by ID you have to set ID attribute instead of NAME.
Third, math is wrong.
Forth...

It's better to show working code. This is event handler:

```
function convertCurrency() {

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
    var inputInches = document.getElementById("inputInches").value;

    switch (dropdown){
    case "feetConversion":
        Convert = inputInches * 0.0833;
        break;
    case "centimetersConversion":
        Convert = inputInches * 2.54;
        break;
    case "yardsConversion":
        Convert = inputInches * 0.02778;
        break;
    }

    var resultsString = "The amount would be: " + Convert;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = resultsString;
}
```

This is HTML layout:

```
<input type="text" id="inputInches"/><br>
Select Conversion:
<select id="dropdown" onchange="convertCurrency()">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="feetConversion">Feet </option>
    <option value="centimetersConversion">Centimeters </option>
    <option value="yardsConversion">Yards </option>
</select>
<div id="results"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ArtyomShegeda/xbj5pf62/13/

Answer (score 1):

1. You never call `convertCurrency`. You need an event listener that calls it. You could put a "Convert" button in the form, and call it when they click on the button.
2. Code like `if (dropdown == "feetConversion".parseFloat(r))` makes no sense. `parseFloat()` is a global function, it's not a method of a string. You just want to compare `dropdown` to the string. `parseFloat` should be used to set the `Convert` variable at the beginning of the function.
3. You don't need an `action` or `method` in a form that's being processed in JavaScript, not the server.
4. You never set the value of `dropdown`. You need to get that from the value of the dropdown. I added an ID to it, and get that using `document.getElementById("selectConversion").value`
5. There's no element `cnvrtMoney`. I'm not sure what the point of `document.getElementById("cnvrtMoney").innerHTML = "output";` is supposed to be. I've removed it.
6. Your conversions are all wrong, you're dividing when you should be multiplying.

```js
function convertCurrency(r) {
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectConversion").value;
  var Convert = parseFloat(r);
  if (dropdown == "feetConversion") {
    Convert = Convert / 12;
  } else if (dropdown == "centimetersConversion") {
    Convert = Convert * 2.54;
  } else if (dropdown == "yardsConversion") {
    Convert = Convert / 36;
  }

  Convert = Convert.toFixed(2);

  var resultsString = "The amount would be " + Convert;
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsString;
}

document.getElementById("convertButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  convertCurrency(document.getElementById("inputInches").value);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

#heading {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
}

#formConverter {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-justify: auto;
}

#EndResults {
  background-color: darkgray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Assignment 01: Currency Converter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="heading">
    <h1> Currency Converter </h1>
    <img src="CurrencyConverter.jpg" alt="Currency Converter Banner" width="600" height="200">
  </div>
  <div id="formConverter">
    <form>
      Enter Quantity (In Inches): <input type="text" name="inputInches" id="inputInches" /><br> Select Conversion:
      <select name="dropdown" id="selectConversion">
        <option value="feetConversion">Feet </option>
        <option value="centimetersConversion">Centimeters </option>
        <option value="yardsConversion">Yards </option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Convert" id="convertButton">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="results">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to rewrite the entire thing, but here it is

```js
function convertCurrency(r) {
 let c = document.getElementById('q').value;
 let v = document.getElementById('c').value;
  
  
  switch(v){
    case "feet":
      result = c / 0.0833;
    break;
    case "cent":
     result = c / 2.54;
    break;
    case "yard":
     result = c /0.02778;
    break;
  }
  
  result = result.toFixed(2);

  var resultsString = "The amount would be " + result;
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsString;
}
```

```css
body {
        background-color: gray;
        }
#heading {
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    }
#formConverter{
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify:auto;
    }
#results{
    background-color:darkgray;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="heading">
        <h1> Currency Converter </h1>
        <img src="CurrencyConverter.jpg" alt="Currency Converter Banner" width="600" height="200">
    </div>
    <div id="formConverter">
        <p>
          Enter Quantity (in inches):
          <input type="number" id="q" name="q">
        </p>
        <p>
          Select conversion: 
          <select id="c" name="c">
            <option value="feet">Feet</option>
            <option value="cent">Centimeters</option>
            <option value="yard">Yards</option>
          </select> 
        </p>
        <button onclick="convertCurrency()">
          Convert
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot needing to be fixed here, but changing the contents of your script tag to the following should work:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById( "convert-input" );
    form.getElementsByTagName( "select" )[ 0 ].addEventListener( "input", function(){
        convertCurrency( this.value, form.getElementsByTagName( "input" )[ 0 ].value );
    }, true );
}

function convertCurrency( dropdown, r) {

    if (dropdown == "feetConversion"){
        Convert = parseFloat(r) * 0.0833;
    }
    else if (dropdown == "centimetersConversion"){
        Convert = parseFloat(r) * 2.54;
    }
    else if (dropdown == "yardsConversion"){
        Convert = parseFloat(r) * 0.02778;
    }

    Convert = Convert.toFixed(2);

    var resultsString = "The amount would be " + Convert;
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultsString;
}
</script>
```

Note that your conversions were incorrect as you had chosen a scaling factor that needed multiplication